# Exchange distribution group behavior when two groups have the same member

Tags: exchange-2013, groups

I'm using Exchange 2013 and I have two distribution groups, DistA and DistB. Each group has UserA and UserB as members.

If someone sends an email to DistA and DistB as recipients, UserA and UserB receive one email only. Is it the correct behavior? I expected they receive two emails because they are in two different groups.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct behaviour.

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/348186-exchange-2010-distribution-group-that-sends-to-all-mail-enabled-accounts#entry-2282459